# Does Fate/Strange Fake take place in the same timeline as any of the Fate/Stay Night routes?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-series, fate-strange-fake

One of the hardest things to wrap my head around in the Nasuverse has been what events belong to what timeline, this is just one example of that.

It seems like F/SF isn't contradicted by anything that happened in the F/SN timeline (that is if you consider the unusual 'rules' of the Fake Grail War to be permissible in the same universe as the normal Fuyuki GW).

So, is it more or less the same timeline? If not, does it belong to any other timelines(like the KnK one for example)?

Comment: considering that Flat Escardos is shown with Lord El-Melloi II unless how Waver became Lord El-Melloi II is different then we know it takes place after the 4th Holy Grail War we see in Fate/Zero

Comment: I haven't read much of the current/ongoing LN series, but in the original one-volume version, there are oblique references to some sort of mysterious ritual being done on an island in the East, which points towards F/sf taking place in the main F/sn timeline. The depiction of El-Melloi also does not contradict anything from Fate/Zero, though it doesn't really provide strong evidence in _favor_ of F/sf being in the F/Z timeline either.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to say, the events of F/Z happening doesn't necessarily mean that F/SN is next. Also IIRC, Waver is El Melloi II in the Apocrypha timeline as well, and there the 4th GW never happened, so it's possible for him to attain this rank through other means.

Answer (score 2):

From the afterword of the first volume:

> I suspect many *Fate* fans are wondering, "This is set after the
>   original Fate, but which route's future is it?" I hate to say this,
>   but, "It's a fake, so it follows a mystery route." I'll leave the rest
>   to your imaginations. In the extra chapter, the two "Observers" leaf
>   through a lot of pages. You can assume that the "world's route"
>   changes with each of those pages.

FSF is set in a parallel world, some years* after the Fifth Holy Grail War, as constant references are made to it: Shirou is obliquely mentionned as a creator of relics, Francesca Prelati took the mud of the corrupted Grail for her own purposes, etc.

*By my own estimation, maybe **2008**. It was the year the April Fool's one-shot version of FSF came out in, but Flat Escardos's age is also an hint: in FSF and in El-Melloi Case Files, he is respectively 19 and 15, and El-Melloi Case Files take place during the year of the Fifth Holy Grail War, meaning 2004.